# Fourier Series MATLAB plotting

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a decomposed triangle wave with various number of harmonics and I am stuck

I was able to calculate the coefficient values and they are in vector form but I can't transform this into my output signal and plot it. I have copied what I have done so far.

I am just getting quite confused and would appreciate some direction.

```
syms t k w_0;

w_0=(2*pi);
k=[1:4]

a_k=(2/1)*(int(2*t*cos(k*w_0*t),t,0,.5)+(int((2-2*t)*cos(k*w_0*t),t,.5,1)))
b_k=(2/1)*(int(2*t*sin(k*w_0*t),t,0,.5)+(int((2-2*t)*sin(k*w_0*t),t,.5,1)))
a_0=(int(2*t,t,0,.5)+int(2-2*t,t,.5,1))


t=[0:.1:10];

%x=a_0+(symsum((a_k.*cos(w_0*k*t)+b_k.*sin(w_0*k*t)),1,2))

for i=[1:4]
    x=a_0+a_k(i)*cos(w_0*i.*t)+b_k(i)*sin(w_0*i.*t)
end

plot(t,x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing everything right, but you are not summing your wave components together. You are just assigning them one after another to `x`, overwriting the last.

Try

```
x = 0;
for i=[1:4]
    x = x + a_0+a_k(i)*cos(w_0*i.*t)+b_k(i)*sin(w_0*i.*t)
end
```

Comment: I think this solves the issue, but you probably need to initiallize with `x=0;`